# how to show current user's inbox in sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts, exchange-server-2007, outlook-web-app

I found [this web part](http://blogs.msdn.com/mahuja/archive/2008/07/01/showing-exchange-inbox-in-moss-2007.aspx) for Exchange 2003, but in exchange 2007 even after user login, web part shows exchange 2007 owa login page (instead of current user inbox).

How I can show current user's exchange 2007 inbox in moss 2007? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a wrapper webpart around the out of the box OWA webpart and have that access the inbox by using the currently logged in user's emailaddress.

Here's the code

**P.S.** *(note that the address of the webaccess is set in the appsettings here!)*

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls;

namespace DCubed.SharePoint.WeParts
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Wrapper around the My Inbox WebPart
  /// </summary>
  public class MyInboxEx : WebPart
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Called by the ASP.NET page framework to notify server controls that use     composition-based implementation to create any child controls they contain in preparation for posting back or rendering.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
      // Create the instance of My Inbox Web Part 
      var inbox = new OWAInboxPart
      {
        MailboxName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email,
        OWAServerAddressRoot = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"]
      };
      Controls.Add(inbox);
    }
  }
}
```