# How to auto login owa web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, web-parts, outlook-web-app

I am working on something like this [sync e-mail outlook2010 and sharepoint2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797453/how-to-sync-e-mail-outlook2010-and-sharepoint2010/11802597) I am looking for a way to log in outlook web parts in sharepoint 2010 automatically using logged in sharepoint user is it possible in C#.. i want to get away from kerberos authentication and configuring exchange server I've tried this one [Get Current User Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012539/how-to-show-current-users-inbox-in-sharepoint-2007) and other similar ones but it didn't work.
any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what in the previous solution didn't work?

Comment: Have you read http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-foundation-help/working-with-outlook-web-access-web-parts-HA101810215.aspx ?

Comment: @Ray signing in to outlook by setting mailboxname property

MailboxName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Email

Not working with exchange 2010

Comment: @PaulZahra yes paul it's explaining how to add outlook webparts..but nothing about auto sign on

Answer (score 1):

Are the login credentials the same as for windows? If so, have you configured the browser correctly? See [browser setup for auto login](http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/how-do-i-make-our-sharepoint-site-stop.html)

To login try the following, inherit from OWAInboxPart and in OnInit create the mailbox name using the current user, for some a simple question mark seems to work:

```
public class MyInbox : Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWAInboxPart
{
    protected override void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MailboxName = ?;
        base.OnInit (sender, e);
    }
}
```

Look at [this discussion of how to get the mailbox for the current user](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/cb9fee12-9d81-41e7-9665-420e1576ae38).

Comment: Yea Paul I've done that but it's not working..I tried it even in sharepoint outlook webpart and it didn't work there either..I am using sharepoint 2010 and OWA 2010..i think these settings would work with OWA 2007

Comment: Hmm... in the discussion thread i posted did you try the suggestion of Jack-Gao's? (three posts from the bottom)

Comment: yes Paul i did..it was one of the first solutions I've tried..these solutions might have worked with owa and sharepoint 2007..but not 2010